# How to extract the contents using Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

Considering the HTML:

[image: Refere this]

I want to select the paragraphs to the left with Selenium. Tried my hand at class_name and id but got NoSuchElementException. Why am I getting this error? I mean the elements are clearly there then why isn't Selenium recognizing those? 
Methods I tried:

```
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id = 'mar-2019']//div[@class='report_data']").text

element = driver.find_element_by_id("mar-2019").text

element = driver.find_element_by_class_name("report_data").text
```

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

To handle dynamic element induce `WebDriverWait`() and wait for `visibility_of_element_located`()

```
element=WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID,"mar-2019"))).text
```

OR

```
element=WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"div#mar-2019"))).text
```

You need to import following libraries.

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple child `<p>` elements within multiple parent/ancestor `<div>` elements. To extract the contents of the `<p>` elements within the parent `<div id="mar-2019">` element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for the `visibility_of_all_elements_located()` and you can use either of the following  [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR` and `get_attribute("innerHTML")`:

  ```
  print([my_elem.get_attribute("innerHTML") for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".data-row")))])
  ```
- Using `XPATH` and *text* attribute:

  ```
  print([my_elem.text for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@id='mar-2019']//div[@class='report_data']//p")))])
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

---

### Reference

You can find a couple of relevant discussions on [NoSuchElementException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47993443/selenium-selenium-common-exceptions-nosuchelementexception-when-using-chrome/47995294#47995294) in:

- [selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element while trying to click Next button with selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50315587/selenium-common-exceptions-nosuchelementexception-message-no-such-element-una/50315715#50315715)
- [selenium in python : NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53441658/selenium-in-python-nosuchelementexception-message-no-such-element-unable-to/53442511#53442511)